# AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' ('Update') object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, attributeerror

I have a problem after transfer my tg-bot to new server. Absolutely no idea why I have error. It seems like I lost some python packets to install. In old server with identical parameters of OS I haven't any problems with this bot.

Sorry if my mistake childish. I try to google my error and haven't answers.

Code1:

```
def start(bot, update):
    if update.message.from_user.username == AAA:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Text_one")
    else:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Text_two")
...
updater = Updater(token=bot_token)

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
```

Error1:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 425, in process_update handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 145, in handle_update return self.callback(update, context)
File "./bot.py", line 43, in start
if update.message.from_user.username == AAA:
AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Code2:

```
def rating(bot, update):
    bot.send_sticker(chat_id,'some_sticker_id')
...
rating_handler = CommandHandler('rating', rating)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(rating_handler)
```

Error2:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 425, in process_update handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 145, in handle_update return self.callback(update, context)
File "./bot.py", line 108, in rating
bot.send_sticker(chat_id, 'some_sticker_id')
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_sticker'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The handler signature is not correct:

```
def start(update, context):
   context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 'Text One')

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
```

Comment: Very strange – on old server my code works correct. Your code now work for me, thank you.

Comment: Now methon sendMessage rename to send_message, by the way. Maybe this information helpful for anybody who read this ticket.

Comment: It is correct, but sendMessage should still work (alias for send_message)